# Confused about entry in windows route table

Tags: networking, routing

Disclaimer: I know very little about this, please humour me with the obvious because I'm probably not aware of it.

I have a windows PC on subnet:

```
192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

its IP is `192.168.0.2`, the gateway is `192.168.0.1`

I have another subnet defined in my router:

```
192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

If I try and ping a machine on the 2nd subnet from the first, I get `Destination host unreachable`.

Doing a `route print` shows the following entry:

```
192.168.0.0     255.255.0.0    On-link
```

Deleting this route enables ping to work, as requests to `192.168.1.x` are then routed to the gateway and into the other subnet.

Adding a DHCP Option 121 (Classless Static Routes) to my DHCP server with a route to `192.168.1.x` via `192.168.0.1` then allows the ping to work (as you'd expect).

**My question is:** why does the route:

```
192.168.0.0     255.255.0.0    On-link
```

exist in the route tables of the Windows PCs by default? Macs connected to the same subnet do not have this entry. Is this a quirk of Windows? Is my router telling my PCs to use this route?

I'm trying to understand why the route is there, and what I can do about it (without manually deleting the route on all PCs), or if I'm approaching this totally wrong.

Thanks

**Update:**

here's my whole route table:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.2     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    266
      192.168.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    266
```

Comment: Could you place your whole routing table in the question (as there must be a route added for 192.169.1.x)?

Comment: When you say you have "have another subnet defined in my router," are the subnets on separate interfaces of the router?

Comment: @JonathanJ its a VLAN

Answer (score -1):

Here is my corrected answer:

> If I try and ping a machine on the 2nd subnet from the first, I get
>   Destination host unreachable.

True without a bridge to link the two networks together

> My question is: why does the route:
>   192.168.0.0     255.255.0.0    On-link
>
> exist in the route tables of the Windows PCs by default? Macs
>   connected to the same subnet do not have this entry. Is this a quirk
>   of Windows?

simple answer YES

Windows can be very problematic sometimes, your pc's have to be in the same lan, have the same workgroup and even be in the same home group for  some of the machines to be able to talk to each other. Sometimes, you can do everything right and it still does not work.

The best way to get into another lan without breaking your current lan settings (that work) is to use a VPN connection.

Most of my friends that have Mac's and Linux computers never seem to as many (networking) problems as windows do.

PS: you might want to check if you have anything in your host or lm host files on your windows machine. I have also seen some people having to change their lan card because they just can't talk with the router.

Again, I would recommend not messing around with rout tables (they are messy enough) and try a VPN connection that you can turn on and off at your will.

Larry Hyman

---

It has been a long time since I did this:

I would say that a PC on the 192.168.1.x range can not ping a pc on the 192.168.2.x range and this is normal

if you want the 192.168.1.x range to talk to the 192.168.2.x range

then you need to have two network cards in each pc connected, pointed to the two default gateways for each network
Or you need to have one computer with two network cards (each network card connected to each different default gateway 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x)

This PC should be running BRIDGE SOFTWARE and will become the new gateway between the two lans.

I can not help you with the Bridge Software, but I do know that you can do this in windows very easy, (and Linux also very easy but you have to edit config files)

Maybe in todays day and age you can by a network box instead of loosing a pc to act as a bridge/gateway, but this is how we used to do it back in the day (about 10 years ago)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt really answer my question. I asked WHY there was a specific route in my windows (but not mac) route tables. Where has it come from, and why? It hasn't been manually added

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but you never explained how you were connecting your machine to the two different networks (192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x) I thought you could not do this with a machine that has only one NIC in it. Whenever you want to connect two networks together and have every pc in each network talk to each other as if all were in just one network, something somewhere has to bridge both of them together.

Comment: I'm going to add a PS to my original post